# How do I install UltraStar Deluxe?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dependencies

I'd like to install UltraStar Deluxe in Ubuntu 11.10. On the [project homepage](http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/usdx-downloads/usdx/) and in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+packages) there are some packages, but they seem to be for an older release of Ubuntu, because when I try to install them, I get complaints about missing dependencies (packages that are no longer available in the 11.10 repositories):

```
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ultrastar-deluxe:
 ultrastar-deluxe depends on libavcodec52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) | libavcodec-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~); however:
  Package libavcodec52 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-52 is not installed.
 ultrastar-deluxe depends on libavformat52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) | libavformat-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~); however:
  Package libavformat52 is not installed.
  Package libavformat-extra-52 is not installed.
 ultrastar-deluxe depends on libavutil50 (>= 4:0.6-1~) | libavutil-extra-50 (>= 4:0.6-1~); however:
  Package libavutil50 is not installed.
  Package libavutil-extra-50 is not installed.
 ultrastar-deluxe depends on libprojectm2; however:
  Package libprojectm2 is not installed.
 ultrastar-deluxe depends on libswscale0 (>= 4:0.6-1~) | libswscale-extra-0 (>= 4:0.6-1~); however:
  Package libswscale0 is not installed.
  Package libswscale-extra-0 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing ultrastar-deluxe (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
...
```

Apart from compiling the program myself and/or repackaging the software, is there a way I can install UltraStar Deluxe in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no optimal solution, but you can manually install the dependencies by grabbing the needed packages from Launchpad.

- First, you need to install some other needed dependencies, that are available in the Ubuntu repositories:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libprojectm2 projectm-data libftgl2
  ```
- Download the files:

  - For 32-bit Ubuntu:

    > [libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb)
    >   [libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb)
    >   [libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb)
    >   [libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_i386.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb)
  - For 64-bit Ubuntu:

    > [libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
    >   [libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
    >   [libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
    >   [libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/2789249/+files/libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb)
    >   [ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/ultrastardx/+files/ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb)
- Install the packages in this order:

  - On 32-bit Ubuntu:

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_i386.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb
    ```
  - On 64-bit Ubuntu:

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i libavutil50_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libavcodec52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libavformat52_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libswscale0_0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe-data_1.1.0-4_all.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i ultrastar-deluxe-songs_20100506-1_all.deb
    ```
- Now you should be able to run UltraStar Deluxe by running `ultrastardx`.